# How to match camera perspective after modelling?

Tags: camera

I'm new to Blender and this is my first big project.

What I have: multiple objects (table and chairs) built using given dimensions to represent the interior of a dining room.

What I want: to arrange these objects and the camera so that they match the perspective of a photo of the real life scene.

What I've tried: I've added the real photo as a background image for the camera view for starters. I also drew some guide lines onto the image to get an idea of the where the perspective line lies. Many guides exist but these seem to nearly all revolve around building objects from scratch onto the background - matching objects to camera rather than camera to objects. I've spent hours rotating and zooming and tilting the camera and I can't seem to get close at all. I know manipulation of the shifts and focal length come into play but I've tried adjusting these and I have no idea whether I was making things better or worse

Here's the closest I've come, I've just been focusing on aligning the table as it's the central piece. You can still see the end of the real table sticking out and the furthest legs won't align, but the dimensions should be accurate. [image: failed perspective on dining room scene]

I'd really appreciate some help or guidance!

Comment: I have considered Blam, but that still seems to revolve around beginning from scratch and reconstructs geometry to match an image. I know my geometry matches as I was provided the dimensions, all I need is to do right now is to correctly calibrate the camera rather than the scene. Please feel free to correct me if I'm misunderstanding how Blam works and if it is indeed the solution to my woes!

Answer (score 0):

I am new to blender but I was deep in photography. My suggestion is to set camera lens in blender to match it with the one which was used to take the real photo(check photo exif data). Also choose the same camera sensor size (!)as it will infulence lens angle of view (either 35 full frame or crop).   Blind guess for 35 full frame as standard. Then I would try to position camera and angle in blender so it will match the photo. Hope that it will help you.  Of course there could be some manipulation done with photo in post production (like perspectice correction done in software not with tilt shift lens). I may only guess that the room is not big enough so the lens are rather wide angle, on the other hand there is no barell distortion so there was some perspective corretion done with software.
So you can export a table render as well and correct its perpective a bit. I know this is not a perfect solution but it may work in this case if you fail matching it. Photo exif data would be a nice start point for me. 
Also, remember that the photo might be cropped, so photo border don't have to match if your goal is perspective